# jQuery Mobile Seems to Prevent ics file from being downloaded

Tags: javascript, php, jquery-mobile, icalendar

I have a page/site written in jQuery Mobile -- http://m.truthuniversal.com -- that creates an ics file, based on an event date an info stored in a database, and it should a allow the user to download or add the event to a calendar via a link that passes the file to another page (download.php) which opens the ics file and echoes the the contents.  It's called this way:

```
        echo"<a href=\"download.php?icsFile=".$icsFilename."\"><img src=\"../images/icon_cal.png\" border=\"0\"></a><br><br>";
```

After clicking on the link, "undefined" is printed to the browser window.  If I refresh the page it then downloads the ics file.

After doing some research, some people say the resolution was to add this  before the jQuery Mobile source is implemented:

```
 <script>
        $(document).bind("mobileinit", function(){
        $.mobile.ajaxEnabled = false;
        }); 
 </script>
```

That does not work for me.  Any suggestions?

-TU

Comment: Some things that I didn't understand: 1) when the ics file is being created? 2) is there any code fired when you press the link you mention?

Comment: Try adding `rel=external` to anchor. This will open links without ajax help.

Comment: @Omar I think that did it.  Thanks.  Thank you for your response as well alkis.

Comment: http://view.jquerymobile.com/1.3.2/dist/demos/#LinkingwithoutAJAX read more here.